# Changes to sudoers have no effect. Following basic Ubuntu tutorial

Tags: 14.04, permissions, sudo, visudo

I'm following along [the Ubuntu sudoers tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers).

Here's my exact `/etc/sudoers` file (screenshot instead of code block because the formatting was getting messed up).

[image: sudoers file]

Notice the lines at the bottom which should give the `deployer` user poweroff and reboot capabilities. The sudoers file is syntactically fine and saves no problem.

I've ended my ssh session and logged in again.

`$ whoami
=> deployer
$ reboot
=> reboot: Need to be root`

What could the problem be?

Some thoughts

- I've tried rebooting (with sudo) and still there's no effect
- My shell is ZSH
- I predict I'm going to kicking myself when I get an answer.

Comment: Please use a code block instead of a screenshot. We now need to copy by hand in order to attempt to replicate your setup. There's no reason why you can't format this correctly, see [here](http://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) for help on how. Anyway, you still need `sudo reboot`, it just won't ask you for a password.

Comment: I know, the screenshot is annoying. I don't understand what is wrong with the code block. I have a lot of experience using them on Stack Overflow but it wouldn't work this time. Anyway, your comment about still needing `sudo` is what I was looking for. If you put that in an answer I will accept.

Comment: Sure, I actually [had it written up already](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/117152/22222) so just a quick copy paste :). I'm curious why you had trouble formatting though. I'm guessing it was the `#` that were being treated as headers. You need a blank line above code blocks for them to be treated as such.

Comment: Exactly. The `#` was being treated as a header and (it looked like it was) forcing the block to be rendered as markdown, which led to massive text sizing. I wasn't aware of the blank line trick so thanks for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The settings you are using will allow your user to run `sudo reboot` *without entering a password*. You will always need to run it with `sudo` though, the best you can get is passwordless `sudo` for certain commands.

This is because of the way the system works. When you attempt to run, for example `reboot`, as a normal user, you get this message:

```
$ reboot
reboot: must be superuser.
```

This has nothing to do with `sudo`, the command in question simply checks whether your userid is 1 (the super user) and if it is not, it won't let you run it. You *could* set up your system to have another user as userid 1 but that would simply change the username of `root` and would be a lot of trouble for no reason (and would not help you do what you are attempting anyway).

So, unless you are actually logged in as the user whose userid is 1, you will *always* have to use `sudo` to run privileged commands. The only workaround would be to create an alias (or a function, or a script) for `reboot` in your shells's configuration file (`~/.bashrc` for example):

```
alias reboot='sudo reboot'
```

That way, since you have already set `shutdown` to be passwordless in `/etc/sudoers`, you will be able to run

```
$ reboot
```

and get your desired result.